# How to run tests of maven project as fast as possible?

Tags: java, scala, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

Imagine you have a multi project structure. A **subset** of the structure is represented on the diagram below.

[image: Module dependency]

Now, you are interested in running the tests for project **A**. But you are developing. In the spirit of TDD you need the feedback-loop to be as fast as possible. Or maybe you are running the tests from a clean slate on a build server.

The alternatives that I see are:

1. `maven test` Slow as maven runs phases `compile` and `test` for **every** project.
2. `maven test -pl A` To my surprise, this doesn't seem to work because maven **will not** build the dependencies of project **A** (projects **C**, **H**, and **D**). As such, test compilation will/may fail.
3. `maven test -pl A --also-make`. This works somewhat. However, maven still runs the tests for every project that project **A** depends on. If lets say project **C**'s tests take 1 hour, that's how much you have to wait to finally have the tests you really care about to run.

What I really want is a way for maven to run **A**'s tests as fast as possible. This would mean, I believe:

1. Compile all source code of the project's dependencies (**C**, **G**, and **D**).
2. Compile the source code of project **A**.
3. Compile the test code of project **A**.
4. Run test code of project **A**.

Is there any way to achieve this with one command?
Is my understanding incorrect somehow?
Is this not a common objective of most people? How do they go about solving it?

(p.s I come from gradle and sbt. There, the equivalent of `maven test -pl A` works as I described here)

Comment: "lets say project C's tests take 1 hour": I think here is a major problem. Long running tests should go the `integration-test` phase, not the `test` phase. Running the `test` phase should generally be fast.

Comment: If you are developing in module A you should run your unit tests during the development from within your IDE (that's the reason why unit tests should be fast) and not from command line(Every IDE Eclipse, IntelliJ etc. can do that if not you have to consider changing your IDE). if you think you're done you will commit the code and push your changes to a CI which builds everything. That should include to run integration tests as well... This approach is not different from Gradle / SBT... that's a general development approach...

Comment: @JFabianMeier Thanks for the answer.
If each Suite of tests takes 5 seconds (~fast), but project A has 100 dependents (whose phases I have to complete first), then running A's tests is no longer fast. Agree?
Regardless, my wording `... In the spirit of TDD ...` was just meant as an example. Regarding moving to the `integration-test` phase, the problem still exists, but now for integration tests. I would then not be able to run the integration tests of project A without running the corresponding phases on all dependents. Does this make sense?

Comment: @khmarbaise
Thanks for the answer.
I completely disagree that the reason why unit tests are fast is because you run them on the IDE. Conceptually, a build tool should be completely independent of the IDE.
What if I use Vim, Emacs, or Visual Studio Code?  
Both Gradle and SBT allow you to do this. That is, to run the tests of a module without 1) running the tests of the dependency modules, but 2) still compiling the dependency modules.

Comment: You can of course run `mvn test-compile -pl A -am` and then `mvn test -pl A` which gives you roughly the thing you desire.

Comment: The reason to use tests is having a fast feedback if something has been broken which you referenced as TDD in your post. And now you say it does not matter? Having fast unit tests is the foundation of TDD or even fast development which usually means you are in your IDE and rerun after each step of change. Using Vim or Emacs does not make sense (no IDE many things not supported etc.) VSC is an IDE as well where you can run unit tests from the IDE...and as @JFabianMeier already mentioned you can run it on command line but that's an exceptional case.

Comment: You misunderstood. I do believe that fast feedback is a cornerstone of TDD.
What I don't agree is you bringing IDE into the discussion to try explaining why maven does not have a way to achieve what I describe on the post.  TDD exists **well before** IDE support for running tests. Running your tests fast should (and is) completely decoupled from your choice of IDE.

Comment: @cmhteixeira "should be" is a philosophical discussion. It isn't and it is unlikely to change.

Comment: @JFabianMeier While I do appreciate you answering, I can't understand why you say `It isn't and it is unlikely to change`. Maybe I am just missing something. Gradle for example, with a "market share" similar to Maven's in the JVM world allows you to do this, and you are not dependent on the IDE. In my past experiences with "Gradle using companies", every single developer ran the tests from the command line.

Comment: @cmhteixeira I see it that way: 95% of Java developers use an IDE which can run tests. They do not need to run them on command line. Maven is developed by volunteers (not a company, like e.g. Gradle). It is unlikely that these volunteers will consider this to be important enough to implement it.

Comment: @JFabianMeier That's reasonable explanation. I will take that.  Thanks.
On a last note, something similar to what you suggested above worked: 1) `mvn install --Dmaven.test.skip=true --pl A --also-make`, followed by 2) `mvn test --pl A`. Doing `test-compile` doesn't update the localRepo (which is reasonable), but `test` does seem to use local repo directly.  Cheers. ;)

Answer (score -2):

1. If the development of module `A` requires changes to dependent modules (`C`, `H`, `D`), then you have not organized the modules correctly. It looks like a violation of the OOD principle *Common Closure Principle* (*CCP*):

> Classes that change together are packed together.

This is true for (maven artifacts) as well.

2. If you have just started development and during the development process the modules change (which is natural), then it becomes unclear where 1 hour of tests for dependent modules comes from. Most likely, at this stage, project testing will take minimal time. If this is not the case, see **point 1**.

Therefore, the following options are possible:

- at the early stages of development, test the entire project and its modules
- when it gets cumbersome (long test execution time) OR modules have stabilized (follow the *CCP*), run tests ONLY for the required module